# How do i insert a new blank cell before current cell that has just been populated

Tags: vba, excel

I have a two (very long) TO-DO lists- one going across and the other going down.

What i want to achieve is for a blank cell to appear at the start of the list instead of having to scroll to the end of the lists to enter a new item.

So then when i have entered an item in a cell and hit enter, i want the cell just populated to move down the list (or across if i hit tab) and a new empty cell to appear at the start of the list.

It would be useful for the new blank cell to be pre-populated with the current date but that is not essential.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your data is severely incomplete. This is not the correct way to do this. Move all your questions from your comments to your post. Detail in **ALL** clarity what you want to happen, not change things as you go along. Gary's answer is perfectly fine, but you keep changing your requirement/description. Ask the right questions if you want to get the right answer. Also, why move the list down? Won't it be better if the data you entered in `A4` is appended to the end of the list? The way I read it, it seems like this is your original way anyway (`...instead of having to scroll to the end...`).

Comment: Garry has given some excellent replies and added some extra code in his second reply to a requests that WAS in my original post but he did not address in the first reply. I am a newbie to excel so i appreciate his advice but you're attitude is quite different. In any case there is a reason i want the list to fill up at the start. Otherwise i would not have asked my question. The only missing link is now to make the ROWS move across independently of each other. If you can help with that solution i would appreciate it. (I hope i have not come across as disrespectful.)

Comment: No disrespect meant as well, but it is bad practice in SO to put in requirements in the comments area. Give it time, you'll eventually understand why. Anyway, I think Gary's code is perfect, that's why I'm waiting for him, but maybe we'll have some problem with the word `independent`, as I find this confusing. Let's say you enter the data in `A4` and press Enter. Assuming the downward list, the value in `A5` moves down to `A6` and the value you just entered goes into `A5`. What else happens? Does the *original* row 5 move to the right as well?

Comment: I'm using his second code only which applies rows moving across. If i have a table of 3 rows say, rows A1,A2 and A3 and then i enter data in row A2 say 3 times consecutively then there will be 3 empty spaces in row A1 and A3. And so when the next time i come to enter data into row A1 or A3 there will be a 3 empty spaces. I want to avoid the other rows moving across nad only the row that i enter data into should move across. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: I understand now. The problem is because you set your range to three cells. I'll be posting a variation ***NOT FOR POINTS***. Wait a moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***NOT FOR POINTS.***

Piggy-backing on Gary's answer, the mistake is that you set `A` to `Range("C4:C6")`. What happens is, when you enter data into any of `C4`, `C5,` and `C6`, they are all moved to the right because of `A.Insert`, which refers to all the cells assigned to `A`.

The trick here is to fully qualify your requirements for `Target`. Let's say you have a table from `B1:E3`, like below:

[image]

Now, let's say you want to move row 1 if you enter something into `A1`, row 2 if `A2`, etc. The following macro should do it (notice the difference with Gary's macro):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim QualifyingRange As Range
    'Dim OrigRng As String
    Set QualifyingRange = Range("A1:A3")
    If Intersect(Target, QualifyingRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        'OrigRng = Target.Address
        Target.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        'Range(OrigRng).Value = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

What is the difference in the above? Very simple but ***very*** important. When a `Worksheet_Change` is in a sheet's code, **every** time you do a valid change to the sheet, the macro fires. The range you just edited will be known to the macro as `Target`. Now, usually, if you don't declare what the qualifications for `Target` are, the `Worksheet_Change` macro just fires indiscriminately. How do we qualify `Target` properly then?

We use `Intersect`. First, we declare a range of cells that we want to track. These cells, when changed, should fire the macro. Otherwise, macro is kaput. This line: `If Intersect(Target, QualifyingRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` basically reads: **If Target is not inside my desired range, then nothing happens.**

This is the reason why I declared `A1:A3` as my QualifyingRange. This way, if my change is to any of the cells above, the macro will fire. HOWEVER, `.Insert` should not be applied to the whole range but to `Target` alone. This is because if we do `QualifyingRange.Insert`, every time a change is detected in any cells in `A1:A3`, all three rows will move. This is what happened when you set `A` to three cells and kept `A.Insert`.

[image]

Hopefully, this clears up the confusion. Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i wanted. You don't know how much work you have saved me. Qudos to you and Gary.

Comment: Kindly mark Gary's answer as accepted if it helped you. This is how we say thanks in SO. :) Good luck with your project.

Comment: Sorry, one last point. In my original post i did say it would be nice if the empty cell at the start of the range could be pre-populated with the current date. Is that easily do-able?

Comment: On second thoughts, leave it. I wont be able to add my data into the same cell as the date which is what i wanted.

Comment: Putting in the date in the cell at the start of the range is easy, in any case. See edited code, the commented-out lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution.  The following event macro monitors entry to cell **A1** .  Once you have entered a value in **A1**, the macro "pushed" the values in column **A** down by one.  This means that value you just entered has been pushed down to **A2** and **A1** is empty:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(A, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        A.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1**

To push across rather than down:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(A, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        A.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

To handle multiple cells, you must specify which cells get pushed across and which cells get pushed down.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for such a prompt reply. However a couple of questions:
1. How can i change the code for the horizontal list? ie how can yo make the cell just populated move ACROSS rather than down.
2. Can i copy and paste the code to multiple cells eg to apply to cell A1,A2, A3 etc

Comment: Also, i started from cell A4 instead A1 and since cell C3 had a coloured background, cell A4 becomes coloured every time a new entry is made and pretty soon the whole column turn the same colour.

Comment: To handle multiple cells I added Set A = Range("C4,C5,C6")
However the problem now is that whenever i enter data into ONE cell then ALL the columns move across. Is there a way so that only the ROW in which i enter new data moves across. Otherwise this method will become redundant as i will get empty spaces for all the other rows. 
BTW I appreciate your assistance with this.